# Label visible using converter doesn't work,in another way i screwed up

Tags: c#, wpf

This looks so embarrassing and most awful to ask question again and again for the same thing.

Really sorry but i couldn't still figure it out or not working as expected

in my previous post @slugster suggested converter ,so used his code like below

MyView.xaml

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <!-- Image Buttons -->
        <Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="visibilityConverter"></Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter>
       <!--Label-->
        <Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"></Converters:BooleanToVisibilityConverter>

 <Label Name="isImageValid"  Content="Image not Created" Margin="0,7,1,0" Style="{StaticResource LabelField}"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="15" Width="119" Height="28" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="True" 
                Visibility="{Binding isImageValid,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

**myviewModel.cs**

```
private bool _isImageValid;                  
public bool IsImageValid
{
    get { return _isImageValid; }
    set 
    {
        _isImageValid = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.IsImageValid);
    }
}

private void OnImageResizeCompleted(bool isSuccessful)
{
    if (isSuccessful)
    {
        this.SelectedStory.KeyframeImages = true;
        _isImageValid = false;
        // isImageValid = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
        this.SelectedStory.KeyframeImages = false;
}
```

when i debug the code,its not even reflect in the UI,when "OnImageResizeCompleted" method called and "_isImageValid=False".Again am lost now.I know i get lot of negative comments but sorry i couldn't able to figure it out myself.

Comment: Don't accept answers if they don't help. Also this is a horrible question, don't talk about "not expected" if you are not going to explain what you *did expect*.

Comment: Sorry H.B,i was testing first time it look like it works but some how i wasn't follow thing properly ,so i tested with different scenario it doesn't work in the morning but my bad already accepted the answer yeseterday.i will make sure in the future,thanks

Comment: It is so unclear what the question is.  Identify the failure scenario with a specific example.  You don't even post the code for the converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, correct `Visibility="{Binding isImageValid...` line. Your view model property is `IsImageValid`.

Second, `OnImageResizeCompleted()` method does not notify UI about `IsImageValid` property changes, it simply modifies property backing field. Change `_isImageValid = false` to `IsImageValid = false`.

Comment: I should bow to you guys to help me so many times for the same issues,finally i have little bit understanding about the binding and how it works,thanks Max to correct the issue.Its working but i have another issue to reset the value to false when its initialize but its not related to this question anyway.thanks again